# how to not open chromedriver.exe when I run my selenium executable

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I made a program that alerts me if there is any seats available
using python, selenium, chromedriver.
Then I made it excutable using pyinstaller with --onefile, -w options since I do not need and I do not want to see any console windows.
But then when I execute my program, chromedriver's console, not sure to call this as a console, shows up.

Is there any way to not see this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the console you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, it would mean that you do not wanna see any browser being open up when you run your script.

If that is the case, I would advise headless mode.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

and then pass the options to driver object like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
```

Using `headless mode`, you would not see any `browser window or console.`Your script will run in background.

Comment: I added that option, but still, chromedriver's console shows up

Comment: Are you doing this in Python ?

Comment: Yes. I am doing this in Python.

Comment: Are you sure if you have passed this `options ` in driver object ?

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: The main purpose of this line `options.add_argument("--headless")` is not to open the browser windows, not sure why it did not work for you.

Comment: It's didn't work, but thank you.